# Create variable conditional on last and current observation variables values

Tags: sas, survival-analysis

Based on the simplified dataset below, I would like to create a new variable X3 that is equal to 1 if the last observation `by` variable `id` has default = 1 and if X1 = X2, `else` X3 = 0.

```
data example;
    input id default X1 X2;
    cards;
    1 0 0 1
    1 0 0 1
    1 0 1 1
    1 0 0 1
    1 1 0 1
    2 0 0 1
    2 0 1 1
    2 0 0 1
    2 0 0 1
    2 1 0 1
    3 0 0 1
    3 0 1 1
    ;
run;
```

The new dataset should look like the following:

```
id default X1 X2 X3;
1 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 1 0
1 0 1 1 1
1 0 0 1 0
1 1 0 1 0
2 0 0 1 0
2 0 1 1 1
2 0 0 1 0
2 0 0 1 0
2 1 0 1 0
3 0 0 1 0
3 0 0 1 0
```

I've tried quite a few things and have been unable to find any solutions. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a variable that controls order? It would be easiest if we could flip the order so you worked of the first of the BY group rather than the last value. Also, please post what you've tried so far, per StackOverflow rules. I'll edit your question to format your data, but you should do that in the future.

Comment: To format code automatically in SAS for SO, highlight code and hit TAB. It will indent automatically so when you paste it here it is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Double DOW-loop is the way to go here:

```
data want;
do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.ID);
  set example;
  by ID;
  if last.ID and default = 1 then last_default = 1;
  drop last_default;
end;
do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
  set example;
  x3 = x1 = x2 and last_default;
  output;
end;
run;
```